# how to calculate inverse erfc while unknown value and constants are involved

Tags: java

I have this equation in java,

double BER = (Erf.erfc(Math.sqrt(3 * CodedEb_No) * Math.sin(Math.PI/8)))/3;

Erf.erfc is from org.apache.commons.math3.special.Erf

I don't know what is CodedEb_No, but BER is 1E-7. How can I calculate CodedEb_No?
I have a hint that I need to use erfcInv()  from org.apache.commons.math3.special.Erf. But, since the rest of the values are also part of erfc function, I am bit confused on how to approach this. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is probably best suited to MathOverflow if you're just wanting this equation rearranged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more of a maths than programming question after a very quick look and not testing, I guess you want to rearrange this function to make `CodedEb_No` the subject. I think that would be

```
CodedEb_No = Math.pow(Erf.erfcInv(BER * 3) /  Math.sin(Math.PI/8), 2) / 3
```

You need to test this carefully!